# Resources$NotFoundException with Robolectric and Flavors

Tags: android, robolectric

I configured robolectric as seen in the deckard-gradle template, everything is fine except the fact that I get this error message when starting the robolectric tests via terminal:

java.lang.RuntimeException: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: unknown resource 2131296262

I know that it's related to the different flavors I use in the build.gradle. I am already using a custom TestRunner for Robolectric, but it is not working anyway, I tried 2.3 + 2.4 SNAPSHOT.

My TestRunner looks like this:

```
@Override
protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
    String manifestProperty = System.getProperty("android.manifest");
    if (config.manifest().equals(Config.DEFAULT) && manifestProperty != null) {
        String resProperty = System.getProperty("android.resources");
        String assetsProperty = System.getProperty("android.assets");
        return new AndroidManifest(Fs.fileFromPath(manifestProperty), Fs.fileFromPath(resProperty),
                Fs.fileFromPath(assetsProperty));
    }
    AndroidManifest appManifest = super.getAppManifest(config);
    appManifest.setPackageName("com.example.android");
    return appManifest;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? My flavors are declared like that:

```
 flavors {
            flavor1 {
                packageName = "com.example.android"
                buildConfigField "String", "GCM_SENDER_ID", "\"807347333395\""
                buildConfigField "java.util.Locale", "locale", "java.util.Locale.GERMANY"
                buildName = "./gittag.sh ${name}".execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
                buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_NAME", "\"${buildName}\""
                versionName = "2.0.4"
                versionCode = 21
            }
}
```

It would be awesome if somebody could provide me some more informations on that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I've just resolved the same problem with Robolectric (ver: robolectric-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and returning unknown resources, while loading resouce from different values-* folders e.g.:

```
<resources>
    <string name="screen_type">10-inch-tablet</string>
</resources>
```

In my case I wanted to recognize different devices. For this reason, I've created screen.xml in following folders:

```
values/screen.xml - mobile
values-sw600dp/screen.xml - 7-inch tablet
values-sw720dp/screen.xml - 10-inch tablet
```

My workspace is as following:

```
workspace
   \-ExProj
       \-exProj
            \-src
                \-exProj
                    \-AndroidManifest.xml
   \-ExProjTest
```

My unit test with Robolectric:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = "./../ExProj/exProj/src/exProj/AndroidManifest.xml")
public class UtilityTest {

  @Test
   @Config(qualifiers = "sw720dp")
    public void testIfDeviceIsTablet() throws Exception {
     System.out.println(Robolectric.application.getString(R.string.screen_type));
    }
}
```

Above test code prints out on the console: 10-inch-tablet...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the path to the manifest in your test as follows:

```
@Config(manifest = "/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class DeckardActivityRobolectricTest {
...
}
```

Comment: What is this path relative to (most answers/blogs I've seen use "../../" or something else relative in their paths)? In other words, I don't understand how to construct the path and what to use as the basis for constructing it.

Comment: The original poster is wrong, you don't want an absolute path beginning with "/", but instead a relative path to the working directory (ie, "./src/main" or some other variant). From what I can tell, the path appears to be relative to the Working Directory for your test environment. In Android Studio, "Edit Configurations", choose your test, and fix the "Working Directory". In Eclipse, I believe there are some setup instructions in http://robolectric.org/eclipse-quick-start/ that detail how to configure the working directory.